# Writing to two tables from a form when there is a PK/FK present

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am trying to write to two tables via a form.

I have a customers table that consists of:

```
-customer_id            int(11) (PK) (AI)
-customer_uname         varchar(20) 
-customer_password      varchar(60)
```

customer_id is primary and auto incrementing. When this is wrote to I am wanting the value to also be wrote into customer_id in the address_book table

address_book table

```
-address_book_id            int(11) (PK)
-customer_id                int(11) (FK)
-customer_firstname         varchar(25)
-customer_surname           varchar(25) 
-customer_addr1             varchar(25)
-customer_addr2             varchar(25)
-customer_town              varchar(25)
-customer_city              varchar(20)
-customer_county            varchar(20)
-customer_postcode          varchar(12) 
-customer_email             varchar(40) 
-customer_phone             varchar(12)
```

Here is the form I am using to pass the user input to the script:

```
 <form action="newmemberscript.php" method="POST">
 <p>First Name:
 <input type="text" name="f_name" required/>
 </p>
 <p>Surname Name:
 <input type="text" name="s_name" required/>
 </p>
 <p>Choose your username Name:
 <input type="text" name="u_name" required/>
 </p>
 <p>Choose your password:
 <input type="password" name="password" required/>
 </p>
 <p>Address Line 1:
 <input type="text" name="addr_1" required/>
 </p>
 <p>Address Line 2:
 <input type="text" name="addr_2" />
 </p>
 <p>Town:
 <input type="text" name="town" required/>
 </p>
 <p>City:
 <input type="text" name="city" />
 </p>
 <p>County:
 <input type="text" name="county" />
 </p>
 <p>Postcode:
 <input type="text" name="postcode" required/>
 </p>
 <p>Phone:
 <input type="text" name="phone" />
 </p>
 <p>E-mail address:
 <input type="text" name="e_mail" required/>
 </p>
 <p>
<input type="submit">
</p>
</form>
```

and here is the script. Writing into customers does not seem to be an issue.

```
$custpass = $_POST['password'];  
$custpass = md5($custpass);  

//write the variables into the database
$sql="INSERT INTO customers (customer_id, customer_uname, customer_password) VALUES ('', '$_POST[u_name]', '$custpass')";

    if($result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
    {
        $customer_id = mysqli_insert_id();

        $sql2="INSERT INTO address_book (customer_id, customer_firstname, customer_surname, customer_addr1, customer_addr2, customer_town, customer_city, customer_county, customer_postcode, customer_email, customer_phone) VALUES ('".$customer_id."', '$_POST[f_name]', '$_POST[s_name]', '$_POST[addr_1]', '$_POST[addr_2]', '$_POST[town]', '$_POST[city]', '$_POST[county]', '$_POST[postcode]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[phone]')";

        if($result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2))
        {
            echo "New member written to database";
        }
    }
```

Nothing is writing into the address_book table at the moment and I cannot figure out why. I am hoping someone can see something that I can't. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What errors are you getting? (hint: if the answer is none, you should be outputting them)

Comment: I'm not getting any errors but I have error reporting turned on, is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: Try an echo on your query's to see what is actually stored inside your $sql.